# LoadLibraryEx error 87 (The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary

One of my applications cannot load a system lib on the only machine. **LoadLibraryEx returns 0** and the **GetLastError returns 87** (The parameter is incorrect).

That can cause such error and how do I debug it?

Error appears only on a single machine which belongs to my client (server 2008R2). Libarary is located in system32 folder. Here is the code:

```
HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryEx(L"authui.dll", NULL,
                            LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);
if (lib == NULL)
{
    DWORD err=GetLastError();
    Log(L"error id: ", err);
    throw;
}
```

I cannot reproduce the error on my copy of 2008R2 and have no idea what can cause the error. My app is written in VS2015 C++ (pure WinApi, no MFC or third party libs) and it is 64-bit.

Comment: Did you read what msdn says about using **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32**? Seems that you need some patch installed first. See [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) doc.

Comment: Oh, I believed I read the doc, but it seems I did not. Will test it with the client ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use an absolute path?

Comment: Because it will add one more line of code to decode %windir%

Answer (score 0):

[Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030219/joel) was right. The problem is in [KB2533623](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533623) update which was not installed on the problem machine. I have changed my code to use absolute path as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) recommended and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path of authui.dll as the first parameter of LoadLibraryEx.